# Testing Expo Constant with Jest, Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs, expo

I'm switching a SDK from Expo managed workflow to Expo bare workflow to reduce some of the unnecessary libraries included in Expo. I'm currently using some of the libraries such as Secure-store, Constants and Web browser from Expo instead of using the entire Expo package. I have some tests originally ran in jest, jest-expo and Expo. I removed expo from jest and trying to compile jest with only those three expo libraries above along with @unimodules. The tests files have import statements such as:

```
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```

However, when compiling jest, it keeps giving me

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>   This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.                                                                >SyntaxError: Unexpected token import at
>   import Constants from 'expo-constants'; >ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript(node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)

Seems like I might have resolved unexpected imports for expo-secure-store since I was getting that error before. I switched from Babel6 to babel7, added a babel.config.js that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      '@babel/preset-env'
    ],
    env: {
        test: {
          presets: [['@babel/preset-env']]
        }
      },
    plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
    ]
};
```

And i'm switching from jest-preset: jest-expo to jest-preset: react-native.

Am I doing something wrong here with the workflow? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I was having this problem and I fixed adding

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
  ]
```

following the guide from https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/

Comment: What part of this code was the fix?  Guide from?

Comment: Added the missing link to Expo guide. It's also explained here:
https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization